# How convert return value in SQL query from cyrillic to latin

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where I store cars registration numbers,
but some registration numbers are in Cyrillic. If I search registration numbers "XX0000XX" where 'X' is in Latin and in table one or more 'X' is in Cyrillic finds nothing. 
Is there a way to write this query, for example:

```
Select from cars where reg_num = 'XX0000XX'
```

in such a way that it can also find the records that contain both Cyrillic and Latin alphabet? In `where` clause string is 100% Latin alphabet

Comment: Which database are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server) ?

Comment: I`m use it MySQL

Comment: Wouldn't the string in your `WHERE` clause already be present in both alphabets?  Long term solution here is to pick a collation which covers all your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use MS SQL. You can use the transliteration function

```
    GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[TransLit]    Script Date: 05.04.2017 10:25:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:  <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[TransLit]
(
 @@String VarChar(max)
)
RETURNS VarChar(max)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @TransTable TABLE(
   Rus Char 
  ,Lat VarChar(2)
 )INSERT @TransTable SELECT 'А','A'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Б','B'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'В','V'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Г','G'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Д','D'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Е','E'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ё','YO'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ж','ZH'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'З','Z'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'И','I'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Й','Y'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'К','K'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Л','L'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'М','M'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Н','N'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'О','O'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'П','P'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Р','R'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'С','S'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Т','T'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'У','U'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ф','F'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Х','H'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ц','C'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ч','CH'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ш','SH'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Щ','SH'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ъ',''''
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ы','Y'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ь',''''
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Э','E'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Ю','YU'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'Я','YA'

 DECLARE @Result VarChar(max)
 SET @Result = @@String
 SELECT @Result = Replace(@Result,Upper(Rus) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CS_AS,Upper(Lat)) FROM @TransTable WHERE @@String LIKE '%' + Rus + '%'
 SELECT @Result = Replace(@Result,Lower(Rus) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS,Lower(Lat)) FROM @TransTable WHERE @@String LIKE '%' + Rus + '%'
 RETURN @Result
END
```

Then your script

```
Select * from cars where TransLit(reg_num) = 'XX0000XX'
```

In 'XX0000XX' use latin.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1150934/Replace-Cyrillic-Letters-with-Visually-Similar-Lat) is s T-SQL solution of this problem. Main idea is that you have to replace all russian С, Х, Н and so on with latin C, X, H. Here are all similar char pairs which were used it this function. You can write your own function that replaces first char of each pair with second.

```
Ѐ -> E
Ё -> E
Ѕ -> S
І -> I
Ї -> I
Ј -> J
Њ -> H
Ќ -> K
А -> A
В -> B
Е -> E
К -> K
М -> M
Н -> H
О -> O
Р -> P
С -> C
Т -> T
У -> Y
Х -> X
Ь -> b
а -> a
е -> e
к -> k
м -> m
о -> o
р -> p
с -> c
т -> t
у -> y
х -> x
ь -> b
ѐ -> e
ё -> e
ѕ -> s
і -> i
ї -> i
ј -> j
ћ -> h
ќ -> k
ѡ -> w
Ҏ -> P
ҏ -> p
Қ -> K
қ -> k
Ҝ -> K
ҝ -> k
Ҟ -> K
ҟ -> k
Ҡ -> K
ҡ -> k
Ң -> H
Ҥ -> H
Ҫ -> C
ҫ -> c
Ҭ -> T
ҭ -> t
Ү -> Y
ү -> y
Ұ -> Y
ұ -> y
Ҳ -> X
ҳ -> x
Һ -> h
һ -> h
Ҽ -> E
ҽ -> e
Ҿ -> E
ҿ -> e
Ӏ -> I
Ӄ -> K
ӄ -> k
Ӈ -> H
ӈ -> H
Ӊ -> H
ӊ -> H
Ӎ -> M
ӎ -> m
ӏ -> I
Ӑ -> A
ӑ -> a
Ӓ -> A
ӓ -> a
Ӗ -> E
ӗ -> e
Ӧ -> O
ӧ -> o
Ӯ -> Y
ӯ -> y
Ӱ -> Y
ӱ -> y
Ӳ -> Y
ӳ -> y
Ӽ -> X
ӽ -> x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution converting Cyrillic to Latin for SQL Server.

```
create function fn_Cyrillic2Latin (@string nvarchar(max)) 
returns nvarchar(max) as
begin

set @string = replace (@string, N'ый'       ,N'y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ЫЙ'       ,N'Y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'а'        ,N'a')
set @string = replace (@string, N'б'        ,N'b')
set @string = replace (@string, N'в'        ,N'v')
set @string = replace (@string, N'г'        ,N'g')
set @string = replace (@string, N'д'        ,N'd')
set @string = replace (@string, N'е'        ,N'e')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ё'        ,N'yo')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ж'        ,N'zh')
set @string = replace (@string, N'з'        ,N'z')
set @string = replace (@string, N'и'        ,N'i')
set @string = replace (@string, N'й'        ,N'y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'к'        ,N'k')
set @string = replace (@string, N'л'        ,N'l')
set @string = replace (@string, N'м'        ,N'm')
set @string = replace (@string, N'н'        ,N'n')
set @string = replace (@string, N'о'        ,N'o')
set @string = replace (@string, N'п'        ,N'p')
set @string = replace (@string, N'р'        ,N'r')
set @string = replace (@string, N'с'        ,N's')
set @string = replace (@string, N'т'        ,N't')
set @string = replace (@string, N'у'        ,N'u')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ф'        ,N'f')
set @string = replace (@string, N'х'        ,N'kh')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ц'        ,N'c')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ч'        ,N'ch')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ш'        ,N'sh')
set @string = replace (@string, N'щ'        ,N'shch')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ъ'        ,N' ')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ы'        ,N'y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ь'        ,N'')
set @string = replace (@string, N'э'        ,N'e')
set @string = replace (@string, N'ю'        ,N'yu')
set @string = replace (@string, N'я'        ,N'ya')
set @string = replace (@string, N'А'        ,N'A')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Б'        ,N'B')
set @string = replace (@string, N'В'        ,N'V')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Г'        ,N'G')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Д'        ,N'D')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Е'        ,N'E')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ё'        ,N'YO')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ж'        ,N'ZH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'З'        ,N'Z')
set @string = replace (@string, N'И'        ,N'I')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Й'        ,N'Y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'К'        ,N'K')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Л'        ,N'L')
set @string = replace (@string, N'М'        ,N'M')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Н'        ,N'N')
set @string = replace (@string, N'О'        ,N'O')
set @string = replace (@string, N'П'        ,N'P')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Р'        ,N'R')
set @string = replace (@string, N'С'        ,N'S')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Т'        ,N'T')
set @string = replace (@string, N'У'        ,N'U')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ф'        ,N'F')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Х'        ,N'KH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ц'        ,N'C')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ч'        ,N'CH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ш'        ,N'SH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Щ'        ,N'SHCH')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ъ'        ,N'')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ы'        ,N'Y')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ь'        ,N'')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Э'        ,N'E')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Ю'        ,N'YU')
set @string = replace (@string, N'Я'        ,N'YA')

return @String
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Macedonian Cyrillic can be coverted to Latin using this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MacedonianCyrillic2Latin (@String varchar(MAX))
RETURNS nvarchar(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @s nvarchar(MAX) = @String

    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'А', N'A')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Б', N'B')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'В', N'V')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Г', N'Đ')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Д', N'D')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ѓ', N'G')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Е', N'E')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ж', N'Ž')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'З', N'Z')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ѕ', N'Dz')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'И', N'I')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ј', N'J')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'К', N'K')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Л', N'L')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Љ', N'Lj')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'М', N'M')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Н', N'N')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Њ', N'Nj')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'О', N'O')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'П', N'P')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Р', N'R')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'С', N'S')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Т', N'T')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ќ', N'Kj')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'У', N'U')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ф', N'G')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Х', N'H')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ц', N'C')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ч', N'Č')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Џ', N'Dž')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'Ш', N'Š')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'а', N'a')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'б', N'b')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'в', N'v')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'г', N'đ')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'д', N'd')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ѓ', N'g')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'е', N'e')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ж', N'ž')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'з', N'z')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ѕ', N'dz')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'и', N'i')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ј', N'j')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'к', N'k')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'л', N'l')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'љ', N'lj')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'м', N'm')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'н', N'n')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'њ', N'nj')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'о', N'o')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'п', N'p')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'р', N'r')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'с', N's')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'т', N't')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ќ', N'kj')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'у', N'u')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ф', N'g')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'х', N'h')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ц', N'c')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ч', N'č')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'џ', N'dž')
    SET @s = REPLACE(@s, N'ш', N'š')

    RETURN @s 
END
```